# Cannot rearrange a tab in product page

Tags: magento

I am attempting to move a tab on the product page in Magento 2. Currently the "custom CMS tab" is showing up before the "details" and the "reviews". I am trying to put that tab behind the reviews so that it shows up as the third tab.

I have tried removing the code completely, but it leaves an empty tab there with no content.

```
         <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" name="page.main.sub.title" template="Magento_Theme::html/title.phtml"/>

          <update handle="page.main.title" />

          <move element="product.info.overview"  destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.review"/> 
          <move element="page.main.sub.title"  destination="breadcumbs-inner" before="-"/>

        <move element="product-cms"  destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.extrahint"/>

    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="cmsinfo.tab" as="cmsinfo" template="product/view/cms_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
         <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Shipping</argument>


         </arguments>
      </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a few months ago and found a solution by @juhanix which worked perfectly for me. By passing a priority argument, we're able to use the argument to position the tabs where we need them to go.

The link to the original question and answer is below:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110796/magento2-change-order-of-tabs-on-product-page